# Mysql - Most efficient way to handle table of vendor/venue pairs

Tags: php, mysql

Lets say that I have two tables. Table 1 is a list of vendors with unique ids (auto_increment). Table 2 is a list of venues or markets at which these vendors might sell, also with unique id's. I want to be able to quickly access whether a vendor is at a certain market. There will be a large number of both vendors and venues. Many application will need to access this information and manipulate it for varying purposes. I am considering two approaches.

Approach 1:

Make a new table with rows corresponding to vendors and columns to venues. A '1' in the a venue's column for a vendor would mean that the vendor is at that venue. This means that when adding a vendor, I am also creating a new column in this third table. I may have a lot of vendors.

Approach 2:

Create a column called venues in the vendor table and a column called vendors in the venue table. Populate the columns with a delimited list of vendor or venue ids. This seems possibly harder to access, but doesn't require a new table with a possibly outrageous number of columns.

The code for implementing each is trivial, so will not be posted here. My question is more of a "best practices" or efficiency question. Thank you.

Comment: I think there is a general consensus here, so I will go ahead and pick a correct answer. Thank you all for your participation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a many-to-many relationship, so you should use a cross-reference table. This table would have two columns - vendor_id and venue_id, with a primary key across both columns.

Answer (score 2):

Neither.

Have a third table with two columns, both foreign keys: vendor and venue.

This is the [standard approach](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_table) and is efficient (at least if you have indexes set correctly). Do not worry about having large numbers of tiny rows. (It is much more efficient then having to extract the data, split it, then make new queries).

Comment: Approach 1 isn't a cross-reference table, it would look like: vendor_id, venue1 (bool), venue2 (bool), venue3 (bool), etc.

Comment: Yeah, I almost did the same thing. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Approach 3:

Make an intermediate (also called junction) table with two columns: `vendor_id` and `venue_id` and Primary Key the `(vendor_id, venue_id)`. The first column would be a `FOREIGN KEY` to `vendor (vendor_id)` and the second would another FK to `venue (venue_id)`.

Also add more columns if you want to store additional data, like when a vendor started selling a specifoc venue, the contact person (of that vendor for that venue, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

What if a vendor can appear at more than one venue? What if you want to see what vendors were at a particular venue on a date in the past / future?

Use a third table (venue id, vendor id, other columns) to decompose N:M relationships. Don't try to store multiple venues nor multiple vendors in a single column. Try not to use booleans - usually they are meaningless - since your question is about mysql at least use an enum type.